# Numpy element wise comparison for a particular value in two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

If I have two arrays as shown below:

```or-tag-here
a = numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
b = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Is there an easy way using numpy to count the number of occurrences where elements at the same index in each of the two arrays have a value equal to one. In the above two arrays, the elements in position(zero-indexed) 2, 5 and 6 are equal to 1 in both the arrays. Thus I want to get a count of 3 here.

Thank you for any help that you may be able to provide.

Comment: This question is not about data-science, it is purely about code and belongs in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways I'll show you (there are probably a lot more using NumPy):

### First method: chaining operations

You can use "masking" followed by the comparison and finally a sum operation:

We want all values in `a` from the indices where `b` is equal to 1:

```
part1 = a[b == 1]
```

Now we want all places where `part1` is equal to 1

```
part2 = part1[part1 == 1]
```

now we are left with all the places where `a` and `b` are equal to 1, so we can simply sum them up:

```
result = part2.sum()
```

### Method 2: built in `numpy.where`

This is much shorted and probably faster to compute. NumPy has a nice function that returns the indices where your criteria are met in some arrays:

```
condition_1 = (a == 1)
condition_2 = (b == 1)
```

Now we can combine the operation by saying "and" - the binary operator version: `&`.

```
part1 = numpy.where(condition_1 & condition_2)
```

To get your desired output, we can take the length of the resulting set of indices:

```
result = len(part1)
```

Read the documentation about [**numpy.where**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to see the other things it can do for you!

Comment: I was getting am error mentioning `the truth value of an array with more than 1 value...use a.any() a.all() ` when I tried the `np.where()` way you show, so resorted to using your chaining operations

Answer (score 2):

I like @RobinNicole's answer - in terms of Mathematics you are looking for a product of two *boolean* vectors.

Here are a few Numpy ways to do that:

```
In [37]: np.dot(a, b)
Out[37]: 3

In [38]: a @ b
Out[38]: 3
```

Here is another more generic solution which will work also for not-boolean vectors:

```
In [48]: ((a == 1) & (b == 1)).sum()
Out[48]: 3
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but only happens to work because OP used `0` and `1` in his example ;)

Comment: @n1k31t4, absolutely! That's why I marked word _"boolean"_ as italian ;) I've also added a more generic Numpy solution

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(a * b)
```

Should do the job:)

As pointed out by @n1k31t4 it only works if you have two arrays that contain only 0 and 1. Otherwise you would have to write something like:

```
 sum((a == 1) * (b ==1))
```

What I find interesting here is that the sum functions treats boolean vectors as vectors with  0 (for `False`) and 1 (for `True`) on which you can perform arithmetic operation (`+` for `or`, `*` for `and` etc..)

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but only happens to work because OP used `0` and `1` in his example ;)